# Eclipse do not put the persistence.xml in my ear

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, persistence.xml

I have an issue and I have no idea why.

I'm developing a EE maven aplication, everything going well, apparently. The persistence.xml is not packaging in the ear. I have the file in the src/main/resources/META-INF

The Java Build Path have the src/main/resources included too. I updated the maven project like 10 times and nothing. I have too many doubts about this, one is that the persistence.xml do not show the task manager (https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/task_manage_persistence.htm). Could you help me please? Many thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any way... i found a solution (i dont know if another one exists) and it was adding the resource into the `<build>` of the pom.xml

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/</directory>
    <targetPath>${project.basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/</targetPath>
    <includes>
       <include>*.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```